# trigger blockui from link within datagrid

Tags: primefaces, datagrid, blockui

I have the below datagrid which displays a list of student names as link.

```
    <h:form id="gsform">

                <p:dataGrid var="stuvar" rendered="#{gradeSheetController.listStudent != null}" 
                            value="#{gradeSheetController.listStudent}" columns="5" layout="grid">
                                <p:commandLink actionListener="#{gradeSheetController.readStudentGradeSheet}" 
                                                        update=":gsform:gscont, :gsform:buttoncont">
                                    <h:outputText id="stname" style="font-size:16px" value="#{stuvar.studentFirstName}" />
                                    <f:param name="selstudent" value="#{stuvar.studentSeq}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                </p:dataGrid>
```

I also have the below blockUI to freeze the screen until backend processing is done, currently used for a Save button.

```
        <p:blockUI block=":entirePageBody" trigger="savebutton">
            <h:panelGrid id="blockContent" columns="2">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif" style="margin-right:12px; vertical-align:middle;" />
                <h:outputText value="Please wait, data is being processed..." style="white-space:nowrap;" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:blockUI>
```

Now, I would also like to trigger the blockUI when the Student name link is clicked. Obviously, since the number of students will be dynamic and being within the datagrid, the code generated includes other aspects to the id like id="gsform:j_idt168:1:stname",  id="gsform:j_idt168:2:stname" and so on.

Have no clue how to trigger the blockUI on click of the Student name link within the datagrid, please suggest.

Comment: Look at the 'client-side api' example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was thinking blockUI can be invoked only using trigger!!

Comment: The documentation and showcase are your friend

Comment: Can you please create an answer yourself so others can see how it should be done?

Answer (score 2):

Triggering/Hiding the blockUI from within dataGrid using onclick/oncomplete

```
    <p:dataGrid var="stuvar" rendered="#{gsExamController.listStudent != null}" 
            value="#{gsExamController.listStudent}" columns="5" layout="grid">
            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{gsExamController.readStudentGradeSheet}" 
                        onclick="PF('bui').show()"
                        oncomplete="PF('bui').hide()"
                        update=":gsform:gscont, :gsform:remarkcont, :gsform:buttoncont">
                    <h:outputText style="font-size:16px" value="#{stuvar.studentFirstName}" />
                    <f:param name="selstudent" value="#{stuvar.studentSeq}" />
                </p:commandLink>
    </p:dataGrid>




<p:blockUI block=":entirePageBody" trigger="savebutton" widgetVar="bui">
    <h:panelGrid id="blockContent" columns="2">
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif" style="margin-right:12px; vertical-align:middle;" />
        <h:outputText value="Please wait, data is being processed..." style="white-space:nowrap;" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:blockUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is to use [Primefaces' selectors](https://www.primefaces.org/jquery-selector-api-meets-jsf/).

For example:

```
<p:commandLink value="Click me." styleClass="blockMeWhenClicked" />

<p:blockUI block=":ElementToBeBlocked" trigger="@(.blockMeWhenClicked)" />
```